# Deleting the Sidebar in the success page

Tags: layout, magento-1, local.xml, sidebar

Hello everyone and thanks in advance for your attention ;

here is my problem :

when a customer completes a purchase, he reaches the "success page" (at the end of the cart and checkout step).

In the success page (www.mysite/checkout/onepage/success/) there is a sidebar on the right with inside some informations (completed orders). I would like to delete the sidebar or at least the content inside it but I can not find the xml file where i should do this ... I have tried in local.xml (in my theme folder) and checkout.xml (in the base folder).

If you want and if i can i will post the code and / or the address of the website.

Here my local.xml :

> 

```
    <reference name="head">

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <action method="addJs"><script>infortis/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>infortis/jquery/jquery-noconflict.js</script></action>

        <!-- jQuery plugins -->
        <action method="addJs"><script>infortis/jquery/jquerytools/tools.tabs-1.0.4.min.js</script></action>
        <!--<action method="addJs"><script>infortis/jquery/jquerytools/tooltip.min.js</script></action>-->
        <action method="addJs"><script>infortis/jquery/plugins/jquery.cycle.2.999.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>infortis/jquery/plugins/jquery.easing.1.3.js</script></action>

        <!-- Other JS scripts
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/scripts.js</name></action> -->

        <!-- CSS -->
        <!--<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/_demo.css</name><params/></action>-->
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/common_skin.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/skin.css</name><params/></action>

        <action method="addItem" ifconfig="themeadmin/mainmenu/standard_menu_enabled"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/menu_standard.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem" ifconfig="themeadmin/mainmenu/wide_menu_enabled"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/menu_wide.css</name><params/></action>

        <!-- CSS: IE -->
        <action method="addCssIe"><css>css/styles-ie-all.css</css></action>
        <action method="addCssIe"><css>css/skin-ie-all.css</css></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie7.css</name><params/><if>lte IE 7</if></action>

        <!-- IMPORTANT: Override/change items added by other modules here: -->
    </reference>

    <!-- Remove and rearange blocks ====================================================================== -->
    <remove name="right.permanent.callout"/>
    <remove name="left.permanent.callout"/>
    <!--
    <remove name="product.clone_prices"/>
    <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed" />
    <remove name="left.reports.product.viewed" />
    <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
    <remove name="right.reports.product.compared"/>
    <remove name="wishlist_sidebar"/>
    <remove name="tags_popular"/>
    <remove name="right.poll"/>
    <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo"/>
    <remove name="reorder"/>
    <remove name="sale.reorder.sidebar"/> -->


    <reference name="right">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>right.reports.product.viewed</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>right.reports.product.compared</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>wishlist_sidebar</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>right.poll</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>tags_popular</name></action>

        <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
        <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="left.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
        <block type="reports/product_compared" name="right.reports.product.compared" template="reports/product_compared.phtml" />
        <block type="wishlist/customer_sidebar" name="wishlist_sidebar" as="wishlist" template="wishlist/sidebar.phtml"/>
        <block type="poll/activePoll" name="right.poll">
            <action method="setPollTemplate"><template>poll/active.phtml</template><type>poll</type></action>
            <action method="setPollTemplate"><template>poll/result.phtml</template><type>results</type></action>
        </block>
        <block type="tag/popular" name="tags_popular" template="tag/popular.phtml"/>
        <block type="paypal/logo" name="paypal.partner.right.logo" template="paypal/partner/logo.phtml"/>
    </reference>


    <!-- Move newsletter to the footer ====================================================================== -->
    <reference name="left">
        <remove name="left.newsletter"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter" as="newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
    </reference>

    <!-- Move cart to header ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- IMPORTANT: new template file -->
    <reference name="right">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>cart_sidebar</name></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="header">           
        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/mini_cart.phtml" before="-">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
            </block>
            <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_mini_cart_above_products">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_mini_cart_above_products</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <!-- Move currency switcher to the header ====================================================================== -->
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="directory/currency" name="currency" template="directory/currency.phtml"/>
    </reference>

    <!-- Links ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- Top links (user menu) -->      
    <reference name="top.links">            
        <!-- Remove "checkout" and "cart" links -->
        <remove name="checkout_cart_link" />
    </reference>

    <!-- Header links -->
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_header_top_links">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_header_top_links</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <!-- Footer links -->
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_footer_inline_links" before="footer_links">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_footer_inline_links</block_id></action>
        </block>

        <!-- Additional blocks with columns of links -->
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_footer_links_column1">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_footer_links_column1</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_footer_links_column2">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_footer_links_column2</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_footer_links_column3">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_footer_links_column3</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_footer_links_column4">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_footer_links_column4</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_footer_links_column5">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_footer_links_column5</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <!-- Predefined CMS blocks (visible on every page) ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- IMPORTANT: additional predefined blocks with links are inserted in the "Links" section -->

    <!-- Add blocks to the header -->
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_header_banner">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_header_banner</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_header_contact">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_header_contact</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_header_top_help">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_header_top_help</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_edgebox_right">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_edgebox_right</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_edgebox_left">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_edgebox_left</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_edgebox_bottom_right">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_edgebox_bottom_right</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <!-- Add blocks to the main menu -->
    <reference name="catalog.topnav">
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_header_nav_dropdown1">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_header_nav_dropdown1</block_id></action>
        </block>        
    </reference>

    <!-- Add blocks to the footer -->
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_footer_company">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_footer_company</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_footer_social">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_footer_social</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_footer_payment">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_footer_payment</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_footer_below_bottom">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_footer_below_bottom</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <!-- Add image callout -->
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_callout_right" before="-">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_callout_right</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

</default>






<!-- %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% -->
<!-- Other layout handles %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% -->
<!-- %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% -->

<!-- PRODUCT VIEW %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% -->
<catalog_product_view>
    <!-- Change default template for product view. IMPORTANT: same as 'review_product_list'. -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>

    <!-- Insert related products into product view (section "product.info") and remove them from the right column -->
    <!-- IMPORTANT: new template file -->
    <reference name="right">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.product.related</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" template="catalog/product/list/related_tabbed.phtml"/>
    </reference>

    <!-- Remove callouts from the right column -->
    <reference name="right">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>i_block_callout01</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>i_block_callout02</name></action>
    </reference>

    <!-- If Ecommerceteam CloudZoom enabled: set CloudZoom media template. IMPORTANT: third party module -->
    <!--<reference name="product.info.media">
        <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="catalog/cloudzoom/enabled"><template>ecommerceteam/cloud-zoom/catalog/product/view/media.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>-->

    <reference name="product.info">

        <!-- Change review summary template: removed links to review page. IMPORTANT: new template file. -->
        <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/summary_nolinks.phtml</template></action>

        <!-- Add block displaying product labels "new" and "sale". IMPORTANT: new template file -->
        <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media.labels" as="media_labels" template="catalog/product/view/media_labels.phtml" />

        <!-- Add tabs -->
        <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>description</alias><title>Product Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>additional</alias><title>Additional Information</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>

            <!-- Add reviews (first part). IMPORTANT: see the second part: reference name="tabreviews" -->
            <!-- IMPORTANT: Do not change 'tabreviews' alias. It is used in JS script in catalog/product/view.phtml -->
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>tabreviews</alias><title>Reviews</title><block>review/product_view_list</block><template>review/product/view/list.phtml</template></action>

            <!-- Add tags -->
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="tag"><alias>product.tags</alias><title>Product Tags</title><block>tag/product_list</block><template>tag/list.phtml</template></action>

            <!-- HOWTO: Add custom tab. IMPORTANT: new template file -->
            <!-- <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>custom_tab1</alias><title>Tab1</title><block>catalog/product_view</block><template>catalog/product/view/custom_tab1.phtml</template></action> -->
        </block>
        <!-- end: Add tabs -->

        <!-- Up-sells: set columns count and max number of displayed items -->
        <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
            <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
            <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>24</limit></action>
        </block>

        <!-- Predefined CMS blocks -->
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_product_right_bottom">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_product_right_bottom</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_product_main_bottom">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_product_main_bottom</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_product_replace_related">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_product_replace_related</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_product_replace_upsell">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_product_replace_upsell</block_id></action>
        </block>

    </reference> <!-- end: product.info -->

    <!-- Second part of adding reviews to tabs. See the first part in product.info section in info_tabs block -->
    <reference name="tabreviews">
        <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                <label>Review Form Fields Before</label>
                <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <!-- Remove product tags block (tags are already inserted as a tab) -->
    <reference name="product.info.additional">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>product_tag_list</name></action>
    </reference>

    <!-- Remove "add to wishlist/compare" links from options box. It is already inserted on product view. -->
    <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>product.info.addto</name></action>
    </reference>

</catalog_product_view>

<!-- CATEGORY %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% -->

<!-- Default category (without layered navigation) -->
<catalog_category_default>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="product_list">
        <!-- HOWTO: Change review summary template. IMPORTANT: new template file.
        <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>short</type><template>review/helper/summary_short_nolinks.phtml</template></action> -->

        <!-- Predefined CMS blocks -->          
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_category_above_collection">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_category_above_collection</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_category_above_empty_collection">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_category_above_empty_collection</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_category_below_collection">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_category_below_collection</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <!-- Remove currency switcher from sidebar -->
    <reference name="left">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>currency</name></action>
    </reference>

</catalog_category_default>

<!-- Category with layered navigation -->
<catalog_category_layered>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="left">
        <!-- Keep layered navigation always on top. Replace: after="currency" with: before="-" -->
        <!--<action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.leftnav</name></action>
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>-->

        <!-- Remove currency switcher from sidebar -->
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>currency</name></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="product_list">

        <!-- Predefined CMS blocks -->
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_category_above_collection">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_category_above_collection</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_category_above_empty_collection">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_category_above_empty_collection</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_category_below_collection">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_category_below_collection</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

</catalog_category_layered>

<!-- IMPORTANT: deprecated since 1.6.0.0 -->
<catalog_category_layered_nochildren>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered_nochildren>

<!-- CART %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% -->

<checkout_cart_index>

    <!-- Predefined CMS blocks -->
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_cart_below_table">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_cart_below_table</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_cart_above_crosssell">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_cart_above_crosssell</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_cart_replace_crosssell">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_cart_replace_crosssell</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_cart_below_totals">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_cart_below_totals</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

</checkout_cart_index>

<!-- CHECKOUT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% -->

<checkout_onepage_index>

    <!-- PRedefined CMS blocks -->
    <reference name="checkout.onepage">
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_opc_above_steps">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_opc_above_steps</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_opc_below_steps">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_opc_below_steps</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <!-- Predefined CMS block below progress block. Inserted directly. -->
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="ii_block_footer_links_container">
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>opc-below-progress-wrapper</value></action>
            <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_opc_below_progress" after="checkout.progress.wrapper">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_opc_below_progress</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>

</checkout_onepage_index>

<!-- SEARCH %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% -->

<!-- Quick search -->
<catalogsearch_result_index>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="left">
        <!-- Keep layered navigation always on top. Replace: after="currency" with: before="-" -->
        <!--<action method="unsetChild"><name>catalogsearch.leftnav</name></action>
        <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>-->

        <!-- Remove currency switcher from sidebar -->
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>currency</name></action>
    </reference>

</catalogsearch_result_index>

<!-- Advanced search -->
<catalogsearch_advanced_index>

    <!-- Remove (RIGHT) currency switcher from sidebar -->
    <reference name="left">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>right_currency</name></action>
    </reference>

</catalogsearch_advanced_index>

<!-- Advanced search results -->
<catalogsearch_advanced_result>

    <reference name="content">
        <!-- IMPORTANT: first remove previous version of the block -->
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalogsearch_advanced_result</name></action>
        <block type="catalogsearch/advanced_result" name="catalogsearch_advanced_result" template="catalogsearch/advanced/result.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                <action method="setColumnCount"><count>3</count></action> <!-- Set column count (from Modern) -->
            </block>
            <action method="setListOrders"/>
            <action method="setListModes"/>
            <action method="setListCollection"/>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <!-- Remove (RIGHT) currency switcher from RIGHT sidebar -->
    <reference name="right">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>right_currency</name></action>
    </reference>

</catalogsearch_advanced_result>

<!-- Popular terms
<catalogsearch_term_popular>
</catalogsearch_term_popular>
-->

<!-- TAGS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% -->
<!-- Change template (previous: 2columns-right) -->
<tag_list_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</tag_list_index>

<tag_product_list>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</tag_product_list>

<!-- REVIEWS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% -->
<review_product_list>

    <!-- Change template (previous: 2columns-right). IMPORTANT: same as 'catalog_product_view'. -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>

</review_product_list>

<!-- CUSTOMER ACCOUNT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% -->
<customer_account>

    <reference name="left">
        <!-- Remove cart from the left column -->
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>cart_sidebar</name></action>

        <!-- Remove Compare block, it is already inserted in DEFAULT section -->
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
    </reference>

</customer_account>

<!-- CMS PAGES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% -->
<cms_page>

    <!-- Predefined CMS blocks -->
    <!-- IMPORTANT: These blocks are removed from home page and 404 no route -->
    <reference name="content">      
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="ii_block_cms_page_top" before="-">
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>cms-page-top-wrapper</value></action>
            <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_cms_page_top">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_cms_page_top</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="ii_block_cms_page_bottom" after="-">
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>cms-page-bottom-wrapper</value></action>
            <block type="cms/block" name="i_block_cms_page_bottom">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_cms_page_bottom</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>

</cms_page>

<!-- Remove static CMS blocks displayed on CMS pages from these pages: home page, 404 no route 
    IMPORTANT: note that IDs begins with "ii" -->
<cms_index_noroute>
    <remove name="ii_block_cms_page_top"/>
    <remove name="ii_block_cms_page_bottom"/>
    <remove name="i_block_callout_right"/>
</cms_index_noroute>
<cms_index_defaultnoroute>
    <remove name="ii_block_cms_page_top"/>
    <remove name="ii_block_cms_page_bottom"/>
    <remove name="i_block_callout_right"/>
</cms_index_defaultnoroute>
<cms_index_index>
    <remove name="ii_block_cms_page_top"/>
    <remove name="ii_block_cms_page_bottom"/>

    <!-- HOWTO: Insert slideshow at the top of the homepage -->
    <!--<reference name="content">
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="xyz" before="-">
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>SLIDE cms-page-bottom-wrapper</value></action>
            <block type="core/template" name="xyzxyz" template="themeadmin/slideshow.phtml" />
        </block>
    </reference>-->

</cms_index_index>

<!-- CONTACTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% -->
<!--<contacts_index_index>
</contacts_index_index>-->
```

My local.xml path : \app\design\frontend\fortis\default\layout\local.xml
Eventually my checkout.xml path : \app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\checkout.xml

I did not paste the checkout.xml due to the limit of characters

Answer (score 4):

Magento is provide to move a block from  layout using tag `<remove name="blockname" />`

As you said you want remove right content aea from the you can do this add below code in layout file

```
<checkout_onepage_success>
   <reference name="root">
    <remove name="right" />
</reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

Alternative: set success page layout to 1column

using below code at layout file

```
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>

</checkout_onepage_success>
```

**It is the better solution**

Comment: hello Amit, thanks for your answer. As you can see from previous comments exchanged, i have not been able to solve the problem. It would seem that the "success page" does not refer to "local.xml" nor to "checkout.xml." (
or maybe I'm wrong something else) . Do you know how I could find the right xml file to edit?

Answer (score 2):

See [Remove Right side bar from continue shopping page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432743/remove-right-side-bar-from-continue-shopping-page)

In local.xml

You could do

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_success>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>right</name></action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
 </layout>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_success>
        <reference name="root">
            <remove name="right"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
</layout>
```

But it may be better to change the template using

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_success>
        <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks both of you for your answers; I tried all the solutions you proposed but unfortunately none of them worked. In fact it is as if they had no effect, I think I'm editing the wrong file but I do not know wich other one i should edit besides local.xml or checkout.xml... any ideas ?

Comment: Edit local.xml is the better option

Comment: Please update your question with your code and path, also did you clear cache?

Comment: wait i will update the question with the code right now; yes, of course I cleaned the cache

Comment: where is `</checkout_onepage_success>...` in your local.xml

Comment: here is the problem... there isn't !I can find it only in checkout.xml but if i edit checkout.xml nothing happens.. i think it is in some other file, but I do not know where else to look

Comment: Can you try add the code to the end of local.xml then clear cache and test again

Comment: ok, wait i will try just right now... thank you for your patience

Comment: nothing to do, is the same as before ; pasted in local.xml "<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
    <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>" but no changes

Comment: change this page/2columns-right.phtml to page/1column.phtml

Comment: nothing, this thing is driving me crazy

Comment: Add test to make sure you local is working eg <catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    <

Comment: nothing seems to be changed; i pasted it in local.xml at the end of the file ; browser cache cleaned before try

Comment: What page did you view?

Comment: homepage, catalog page, cart, checkout and success page

Comment: Does you local have the following format `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">...</layout> `

Comment: here my "head" of local.xml :   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>......content</layout>

Comment: You seem to have an issue with your local.xml (maybe you editing the incorrect one) but the could above should work

Comment: i don't know... that one is the only one "local.xml" file in the entire server; i think that, maybe, the success page is referring to some other xml but i don't know wich one.. there is a way to discover wich xml is using the success page ?

Comment: Is this code on a dev server?

Comment: the website is on a cloud server; os linux ; cpanel and, obviously php (5.5) installed .

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing this in the checkout.xml? If you are using a checkout extension, you may have to check their layout files, its possible that their settings are overriding the default settings.

Here is what i'm seeing around line 479.

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
   <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
   <reference name="root">
       <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
   </reference>
   <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

change reference name="root" to:

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate">
       <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its been 3 years of this question but I had the similar kind of issue. The code which did the tweak is below:

In theme/layout/checkout.xml, find

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
        <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
```

And replace with:

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
        <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
```